# How to define two polyhedron intersect or not?

Tags: computational-geometry

Recently I have used Mathematica to simulate the concrete structure.
The most important point is generate random concrete aggregate.
As you know, concrete aggregate can be looked as a polyhedron.

We can use ConvexHull to generate polyhedron.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];

data3D = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
Graphics3D[Point[data3D]];

{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]];
```

[image]

Question 1: How to define two polyhedron intersect or not?

I have written a Module, But its speed is very slow.

Question 2: When the concrete aggregate become more and more in a cubic region, it is very difficult to add new aggregate in the region, How can deal with this problem ?

The key is define the space relationship between line(segment) and plane(triangle):

```
HelenFormulaofTriangle[triangle_] := Module[
   {a, b, c, p},

   a = Norm[(triangle[[1]] - triangle[[2]])];
   b = Norm[(triangle[[1]] - triangle[[3]])];
   c = Norm[(triangle[[2]] - triangle[[3]])];

   p = 0.5*(a + b + c);

   Sqrt[p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)]

   (*
   triangle={{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}};
   HelenFormulaofTriangle[triangle];
   *)

   ];



PointInandOnorOut3DTriangle[point_, triangle_] := Module[
   {},

   If[
    HelenFormulaofTriangle[{point, triangle[[1]], triangle[[2]]}] + 
      HelenFormulaofTriangle[{point, triangle[[1]], triangle[[3]]}] + 
      HelenFormulaofTriangle[{point, triangle[[2]], triangle[[3]]}] > 
     HelenFormulaofTriangle[triangle],
    0,
    1]



   ];


   triangle={{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}};
   HelenFormulaofTriangle[triangle];
   point={0,0,1};
   PointInandOnorOut3DTriangle[point,triangle];
```

[image]

Comment: For the first question, do you mean "how to decide if 2 polyhedrons are intersecting"? Then, I can't understand your second question very well.

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Yes,I mean how to decide if 2 polyhedrons are intersecting

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and format your code just as [@jtbandes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/929/jtbandes) did for you.

Comment: I have paste my code.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where's the definition of `PointInandOnorOut3DTriangle`? Also, I think `IntersectofLineTriangle` isn't a function that "decide if 2 polyhedrons are intersecting".

Comment: Does your have an email adress? I will send it to you to have a look

Comment: It'll be good if you can check your code before pasting it here, now, where's the definition of `IntersectofTwoTriangles`? Still, you didn't explain the meaning of your _question 2_.

Comment: NO,that is an text erron. I donnot use this functions. and i have pasted my codes, and intersecting of two polyhedrons can been checked recursely by checked one polyhedron's edges with another polyhedron.

Comment: NO,that is an text erron. I don not use this functions. and i have pasted my codes, and intersecting of two polyhedrons can been checked circulate by checked one polyhedron's edges with another polyhedron. The problem is how to accelerate codes

Comment: OK, then what's the meaning of "When the concrete aggregate become more and more in a cubic region, it is very difficult to add new aggregate in the region, How can deal with this problem"?

Comment: The problem is to fill with a cube zone (eg. size 100*100*100) with the concrete aggregate( the aggregate is treated as a polyhedron ).....Now the problem become to: (1)generate polyhedrons (2)throw them into the zone. the polyhedron do not intersect each other. Your can look at a picture. I paste it on the codes

Comment: Well, as @Nasser mentioned above, it's not so proper to ask _question 2_ here. (It's a little too board. ) As to the 1st question, have you looked into [Simplex](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplex.html), [RegionIntersection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html), [RegionMember](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html) in v10?

Comment: It seems that RegionIntersection can not be used to deal with ConvexHull or 3D objects.But it can be used for 2D objects

Comment: Well, if you want to call someone who isn't the original poster that appearing in the comment, you need to add @someone in your comment, or others won't see the reminder. `RegionIntersection` can be used for 3D object, for example `d1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
d2={{0,0,0},{1/2,1/2,1/2},{1,0,0},{1,1,0}};r=RegionIntersection@@(Tetrahedron/@{d1,d2});RegionMember[r,{x,y,z}]//Reduce`